# How to prepend auto incrementing number to array?

Tags: arrays, perl, file

I am reading file contents in perl by following code

```
my @files = glob("$PATH/*");
foreach my $file (@files){
    open(MYFILE,"<$file");
    my @fileContent = <MYFILE>;
    close(MYFILE);
}
```

Now, I want to prepend auto-incrementing number to each line. Something like --

```
fileContent[0] = 1: This
fileContent[1] = 2: is
fileContent[2] = 3: a
fileContent[3] = 4: text
fileContent[4] = 5: file.
```

Does someone know an efficient way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about a one-liner?

```
perl -wne 'print "$.: $_"; close ARGV if eof;' path/*
```

Or inside a script, with an array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

while (<tmp/data*>) {
    open my $fh, '<', $_;
    my @fileContent;
    push @fileContent, "$.: $_" while <$fh>;
}
```

Documentation on `$.` [here.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER)

Comment: You could also use [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) if you need to format the number (e.g., to a certain width), and I'd recommend checking out [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for further information on `$.`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The script one suits me the best! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your assignment line:

```
my $i;
my @fileContent = map{++$i.":  $_"} (<MYFILE>)
```

Comment: This may be a bit slow on large files, but can easily be transformed into a `for` loop to overcome that problem.

Comment: Hey! Looks nice but how large file you are talking about?

Comment: Large in computer terms. Large as in, takes a long time to load all from disk or can't be read into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Efficient?  I don't know that there is really an *inefficient* way to do it (unless you make it inefficient on purpose).

```
for my $lineNumber (1..@fileContent) {
    substr( $fileContent[$lineNumber-1], 0, 0, "$lineNumber: " );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I thought looping would be inefficient way to do it as it am doing this for multiple files and each file has hundreds/thousands of lines.

Comment: A `for` loop is probably the fastest way of doing this. And, it's pretty fast too. Doing hundreds of files and each has hundreds or thousands of lines won't take more than a minute. You can use the Perl `map` function. It's shorter because it takes one line of code, It's cooler too because when we use it, the girls swooning _"Oh, he's so hot! He knows how to use the Perl "map" command_. However, the `map` is probably slower in executing than a `for` loop.

Comment: @David All the cool girls *do* say that. It is known. However, `while` might be preferable where memory usage is concerned.

Comment: @TLP: You're correct about the while command taking less memory.

Comment: the overhead of reading the file is going to make any other time efficiency insignificant.  if you are talking about memory efficiency, from your original example I assumed you needed the whole file loaded in memory.  If not, that's a much bigger opportunity for efficiency than how you add the line number

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, edited to use lexical variables, 3 arg open, and a map statement to add the line numbers.

```
my @files = glob("$PATH/*");
foreach my $file (@files){
    open my $fh,'<', $file or die $!;
    my $i = 1;
    my @fileContent = map {$i++.": $_"} <$fh>;

    # do something with @fileContent
}
```

Here is an example that is a bit more perlish (using more of the automatic features):

```
for (<$PATH/*>) {
    local @ARGV = $_;
    my $i = 1;
    my @lines = map {$i++.": $_"} <>;

    # do something with @lines
}
```

And here is an example that makes use of `$.` (the input line number) and a while loop to read the file line by line.

```
for (<$PATH/*>) {
    local (@ARGV, $_) = $_;
    my @lines;
    push @lines, "$.: $_" while <>;

    # do something with @lines
}
```

Comment: I did a quick test and the numbers reset at least with perl 5.12

Answer (score 0):

Change your open to:

```
open MYFILE, '-|', 'grep', '-n', '', $file
```